# Do we not need to have a USING statment for LINQ to Entites in ASP.NET 5/EF7 anymore?

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I worked with Entity Framework 6 in my ASP.Net 4.6 projects I would do build a LINQ to Entities query like this

```
using (var db = new ForumContext())
{
    var model = db.yaf_Message
                    .Where(yt => yt.yaf_Topic.ForumID == 2 && yt.ReplyTo == null)
                    .Include("yaf_Topic")
                    .OrderByDescending(yt => yt.yaf_Topic.Posted)
                    .Select(yt => new NewsVM()
                    {
                        PostedBy = yt.yaf_Topic.UserDisplayName,
                        RawDatePosted = yt.yaf_Topic.Posted,
                        RawSubject = yt.Message,
                        Title = yt.yaf_Topic.Topic,
                        TopicID = yt.TopicID
                    }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

I am now working in an ASP.Net 5 (MVC 6) application using Entity Framework 7, to my surprise when I started to write out the LINQ inside my using statement Intellisense did not pick up any table names. So I pulled up an MS Tutorial on doing queries in Entity Framework 7 and found [this page](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html#add-an-index-page). To my surprise they are not making a new instance of the context but they look to be using Dependency Inject to do all the work and they are not calling a `USING` statement at all.

So do we not need to do a that anymore and DI just takes care of everything for us now?

Comment: `So do we not need to do a that anymore and DI just takes care of everything for us now?` Pretty much, yep.

Comment: That's not new. Most DI providers have always been capable of managing object life cycles. The difference is that now there's a provider off the shelf (Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection).

Comment: @GertArnold I have actually never used DI so I did not know that. If you or Drew Kennedy want to write up a little blurb about that as an answer I will accept it. I am sure this might confuse a few other Jr. programmers moving from .Net 4 to .Net 5 who have also not used DI before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Gert Arnold in the comments ASP.Net Core now has it's own DI framework that is used with EF Core. With the usage of DI the old methods do not work, you simply create an instance with DI and call right into that as can be seen in [the documents.](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html)